# BLoC emit not updating the state in UI

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have build the screen with Appbar,Tabs and TabView, the Appear has TextField, every time text changes, the control is going inside the BLoC's emit but never received at UI. Please find the code below, I appreciate your any help.

```
class Buildings extends StatefulWidget {
  const Buildings({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BuildingState();
}

class _BuildingState extends State<Buildings> {
  late TextEditingController _searchController;
  late NearbybuildingsBloc nearbybuildingsBloc;
  late AllbuildingsBloc allbuildingsBloc;
  late String _searchText='';
  late BuildContext allBuildingContext;
  @override
  void initState() {
    nearbybuildingsBloc = NearbybuildingsBloc();
    allbuildingsBloc = AllbuildingsBloc();
    _searchController = TextEditingController();
    _searchController.addListener(() {
       _searchText = _searchController.text;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<NearbybuildingsBloc>(create: (context) => nearbybuildingsBloc..add(NearbyBuildings())),
        BlocProvider<AllbuildingsBloc>(create: (context) => allbuildingsBloc..add(AllBuildings()))
      ],
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: AppColor.bt_indigo,
            title: TextField(

              onChanged: (value) {

                allbuildingsBloc.add(
                  SearchbuildingLoadingEvent(query: _searchText),
                );
              },
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              controller: _searchController,
              decoration:  InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: _searchText.isEmpty
                    ? null
                    :IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () => _searchController.clear(),
                ),
                isDense: true,
                hintText: 'Building name',
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: AppColor.border_color),
                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 2,
                      color: AppColor.text_editor_background),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 2,
                      color: AppColor.text_editor_background),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
                fillColor: AppColor.text_editor_background,),
            ),
            actions: [
              NamedIcon(
              text: '',
              iconData: Icons.filter_list_alt,
              onTap: () {
                /*showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    barrierDismissible: true,
                    builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
                      return StatefulBuilder(
                          builder: (buildContext, state) {
                            return _openFilterCategoryDialog(
                                filterCategories, context, state);
                          });
                    });*/
              },
            ),
              NamedIcon(
                text: '',
                iconData: Icons.help,
                notificationCount: 1,
                onTap: () {
                },
              )],
            bottom:
            _searchText.isEmpty? TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Near by'),
                Tab(text: 'All Buildings')
              ],
            ):null,
          ),
          body:  _searchText.isEmpty?TabBarView(
            children: [
              // Nearby buildings
              BlocBuilder<NearbybuildingsBloc, NearbybuildingsState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if( state is NearbybuildingsLoading){
                   return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: AppColor.bt_indigo,
                    ));
                  }
                  if(state is NearbybuildingsGpsPerm){
                    return row.getGPS(context);
                  }
                  if (state is NearbybuildingsLoaded) {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Showing ${state.nearBuildingList.length.toString()} buildings ", style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,

                            color: AppColor.bt_indigo,
                            fontFamily: 'BT Regular'),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: state.nearBuildingList.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                                return row.getRow(state.nearBuildingList[position], context);
                              }),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }

                  return const Text("Failed to load buildings");
                },
              ),

              // All buildings
              BlocBuilder<AllbuildingsBloc, AllbuildingsState>(
                builder: (context, state) {

                  if( state is AllbuildingsError){
                    return const Text("Failed to load buildings");
                  }

                  if (state is AllbuildingsLoaded) {
                    return  Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Showing ${state.all.length.toString()} buildings ", style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                            color: AppColor.bt_indigo,
                            fontFamily: 'BT Regular'),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: state.all.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                                return row.getRow(state.all[position], context);
                              }),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  return const Text("Failed to load buildings");
                },
              ),
            ],
          ):

              // All buildings
              BlocBuilder<AllbuildingsBloc, AllbuildingsState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if( state is SearchbuildingLoadingState){
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: AppColor.bt_indigo,
                    ));
                  }

                  if (state is SearchBuildingLoadedState) {
                    return  Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Showing ${state.searchresults.length.toString()} buildings ", style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                            color: AppColor.bt_indigo,
                            fontFamily: 'BT Regular'),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: state.searchresults.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                                return row.getRow(state.searchresults[position], context);
                              }),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  return const Text("Failed to load buildings");
                },
              ),


          // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**State**

```
class SearchBuildingLoadedState extends AllbuildingsState{

  List<Building> searchresults;
  SearchBuildingLoadedState({required this.searchresults});

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [searchresults];
  }
}
```

**Event**

```
class SearchbuildingLoadingEvent extends AllbuildingsEvent {

  final String query;

  SearchbuildingLoadingEvent({required this.query});
  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [query];
  }
}
```

**BLoC**

```
class AllbuildingsBloc extends Bloc<AllbuildingsEvent, AllbuildingsState> {
  AllbuildingsBloc() : super(AllbuildingsInitial()) {
    on<SearchbuildingLoadingEvent>(_onSearchBuilding);
  }

  Future<void> _onSearchBuilding(SearchbuildingLoadingEvent event, Emitter<AllbuildingsState> emit) async {
    emit(SearchbuildingLoadingState());
    if(event.query.isNotEmpty || event.query.isNotEmpty) {
      final database = await $FloorAppDataBase
          .databaseBuilder('bootcamp-instagram-project.db')
          .build();
      final buildingDao = database.buildingDao;
      var getBuilding = await buildingDao.getSearchBuildings(
          event.query);
      if (getBuilding != null) {
        emit(SearchBuildingLoadedState(searchresults: getBuilding));
      } else {
        emit(SearchbuildingNoDataState());
      }
    }else{
      emit(SearchbuildingNoDataState());
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the tab bar view to have three bloc builders where you provided,

whether you can try with
changing the tab controller

```
DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
```

and add 1 more tabbar here

```
TabBar(
       tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'Near by'),
            Tab(text: 'All Buildings')
          ],
      )
```

Comment: Nope…Apologies…the issue is in Flutter architecture…I got the answer by my own and will post soon…lots of learning there and definitely should help others